# What is a good design for nested stl containers with multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, stl, containers, tbb

I am having a hard time to figure out what can be a well-organized and efficient design for the following objects that I have as part of a bigger project.

Please note that I am having multiple threads working on the objects, some reading, and others writing into the objects.

I have a large stl vector of objects let's say Nodes. Each node has some attributes plus 2 small stl vectors. 
Threads may modify objects and the two vectors inside them.

I know stl vectors are not thread safe, and I have to provide it, but I think it's easier to use intel TBB rather than stl vector for the large vector. I tried this but I'm getting segmentation faults as threads may modify the two smaller vectors inside Nodes, as they can be stored outside of the Node's space and therefore TBB's concurrent_vector does not protect them, even though they are attributes of the Node.(Please correct me if I'm wrong.) 
Now I am thinking to removing the large stl vector and keep nodes as just free nodes in the heap. At least this way I can better provide synchronization. But I doubt I can make it as fast as intel TBB. I cannot use intel TBB's vector anyway, because it does not protect the small internal vectors inside Nodes. (For some reason I have to keep the internal vectors as stl vectors).

Now my question is that "Is this a good and efficient design?"
Any comment is appreciated.

```
Class All
{
 tbb::concurrent_vector<Node> MyArray;
}

Class Node
{
    void inline Check_Set_lock ();
    void inline Unset_lock ();

    std::vector<pair<int,int> > MBR;    
    std::vector<double> Measures;
    omp_lock_t xlock;
}
```

Please note I have to use an openmp lock plus two lock/unlock methods to protect Node objects. I also know about Boost threads, but here again I am having a hard time if I should choose Boost threads to provide separated read and write locks? I think openmp does not provide shared locks.

My last question is can I only use the xlock in the code to protect all attributes and the stl vectors inside each Node when it's being read/written by a thread? I think this will degrade the parallelism, but what would be a better choice?

Comment: There is one thing that isn't clear to me: Which code adds elements to the array of nodes? This code might be the culprit when getting segfaults with native C++ vectors. Adding an element can reallocate the storage, copying all contained elements. For such cases, std::list provides better separation. Another issue I'm wondering about is that the mutex (omp_lock_t) seems to be copied, i'd expect it to be non-copyable. Anyhow, leaving the low level, what are all those threads doing on that data? I'd expect lots of race conditions if they are  reading and writing with such fine-grained locking.

Comment: I used the concurrent_vector of TBB. It does not relocate. So I think the problem is somewhere else. for the omp_lock_t, each time I create a Node object including the lock. Then I push it into the concurrent_vector. Do you mean this copying is wrong? But when I try the code with 1 thread, it locks and works fine. I expect if I set a default size for the internal vectors they should not relocate and locks on them should work properly. But I still get seg. faults.

Comment: Concerning the copying, generally you can't copy things like mutexes, so two things could happen: Either the copied thing is just a handle, then copying the handle poses the question of ownership and cleanup. Or, the thing is a structure containing the data for the mutex, then copying is dangerous. I haven't found any clear docs, so I'd assume you can't copy it. How do you "set a default size" for the internal vectors? Now, to address the question about the efficiency of your design, it's generally better to cooperate instead of competing for locks, but I'm not sure if you can do that.

Comment: The default size like std::vector<Node> MyArray(1000) with 1000 elements. I assume as long as there are less than 1000 elements, the vector does not relocate. How to cooperate? The threads that read, can cooperate without any lock. But as soon as I add writer threads, I need to have a mutex, so they have to compete.

Comment: You are right about the mutex copying. This should be one of the problems.

Comment: Can you say more about the operations on the Nodes?  Are the operations always mutating, or mostly read-only?  If the latter, a tbb::spin_rw_mutex might improve concurrency.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly the details of the design, but for ideas take a look here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism Maybe you can come up with something.